# How do you change the parallaxratio on CCParallaxNode at runtime?

Tags: ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I want to change the parallaxratio of CCParallaxNode from left to right (vice versa) at runtime.  I can only see that it is set only when you add your child. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: Basically I wanted to achieve is something like the A3ParallaxScrollView  but on CCNode not UIView.   I don't want to add UIView on top of CCNode class.